# Dragging a GridViewitem from a GridView to create a copy (leaving the item in the gridview)

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, winrt-xaml

I'm developing a Windows Store App which has a gridview that is used like a "Toolbox" from which I want to be able to drag items onto another control.

The default animation of dragging removes the item from the GridView while the item is being dragged and then the item snaps back to the GridView after the item is dropped on the destination component.

Is it possible/easy to allow the item (or items in the case of multi-selection) to be shown at the mouse/touch location during the drag while also remaining within the GridView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The quick answer is no. Especially since you said "easy way". The concept of adorners which is in WPF isn't part of WinRT. You can always create something that floats under the pointer, for sure. That's a real option. But drag and drop is only partly implemented in W8.x XAML.

Comment: Thanks for replying.  I had suspected as much when I couldn't spot anything obvious but being new to this API I wasn't sure.  Any chance you would be able to point me to which part of the API you would use to draw something under the cursor?

Comment: But Windows 10 will be a different answer!